# Joomla Multiple language

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.7

I installed joomla language extension and it works fine with the Joomla Administration panel. Now my requirement is to provide language changing option on my front end. Let's say once someone select French he should get existing French articles. And if he change the language to English he should get English articles.

I searched google, but I couldn't get any clue how to get done this. Any help or article highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found relevant language extensions from following link.

http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/jtranslation1_6/frs/?action=index

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, when you submit an article / add them / whatever you can tag them with the language and then load it from there.

And of course if you are taking articles from a whole bunch of other sites, what you can do to automate this process is to take 300-500 of the most used words / characters that are specific to that particular language and then determine it from there. If you get other articles that you cannot determine, add more words or do it manually

protip: words like "or" and "and" are quite often used consider using them

Comment: Thanks for the answer. All the articles compose by users. No automate system. Assume the web site load in English by default. How can I set language change facility to French from my site.

Comment: In order to do that you would need to load the HTML document of the page and put it onto your server (really risky make sure your sources are safe) and then use Joomla to translate it and redirect the user to the page on your site

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Joomla 1.5, you may be interested in this component:

[Joomfish](http://www.joomfish.net/)

It doesn't work exactly as you said. For example, if you create your articles in English, you can translate them, so when a user views your site in French, he will get the French translation of that article, or the English version of the article if you haven't translated it.
This component also bundles a language switcher module.

If you're using Joomla 1.7, you already have a language switcher module and a language manager, but I think it won't fit to your needs if you need to have completely different articles for different languages, it's intended to have the same articles in different languages.

I hope it helped!